Jito bundle with dependent transactions?
How would I be able to successfully send a bundle with both a create and buy transaction (from two different addresses)? The bundle sends to Jito but never lands. It seems like the buy tx is unable to successfully gather the token info as it is in the same block and therefore is unsuccessful every time.
Strangely, if i add a buy to the same transaction as the create instruction (from same wallet) it is able to run successfully.

You're gonna need to send in some code if you hope to get help. I.e.:
How are you sending bundles? Where are you buying tokens?
In my experience, both RaydiumSDK and Jupiter API take care of the acc creation instruction for you. So you don't need to explicitly create anything. Just buy.
And you need to make sure that you sign the bundle with both signers, if you're trying to push through txs from multiple diff wallets.
